# How to check if my phone has the Lumia Denim update?

Tags: update, nokia-lumia-1020, lumia-denim-update

How to check whether my Lumia 1020 has the Denim update? I recieved a big update yesterday, but I can't see Denim in Settings -> About.

My current OS version: 8.10.14234.375.

Comment: This Denim update process has been confusing. My phone has been on the Denim firmware number for my country variant for a while, but Extras+Info still says Cyan, and the official WP page says my operator variant is still Cyan. My OS version also does not match either variant. I'm just holding out for Windows 10.

Answer (score 4):

You can see what firmware you are running by going to `Settings` > `Extras + Info`.

Comment: "*Lumia Denim isn't even available for the 1020 yet.*" Incorrect, Denim is available for the 1020 in many countries. See [this page](http://www.microsoft.com/en/mobile/support/software-update/wp8-software-update) for more information.

Comment: @Indrek Thanks! I thought I was on that page, but it was actually another one. Edited.

Comment: I checked and I saw Denim but why No 2K recording in video Lumia camera?

Comment: I believe you mean 4K. Microsoft warned that not all phones will be able to make use of all features. I don't know for certain, but that may be a feature the 1020 can't implement.

Comment: Lack of 4K video support on the 1020, as well as other first-gen WP8 handsets is most likely due to limitations of the older hardware platform. AFAIK, the only Lumias supporting 4K video are the ones based on the newer Snapdragon 800 chipset (i.e. 930, Icon and 1520).